# Is sheetrock/drywall required under woodpanelling?

Tags: drywall, framing

I live in an old house, built in 1940's. I have a wall between two bedrooms that bowed out terribly. It is not a supporting wall. I am pulling this wall out, reframing it, and installing 3/4" tongue-and-grove beetle-kill panelling. Is sheetrock/drywall required under the wood?

Comment: Ask your building codes dept; that *may* settle the question. Drywall under the tongue-and-groove wood  would give sound insulation, act as a fire barrier, and confer shear strength. Look up construction techniques for installing paneling. Minimal taping and bedding would be required under paneling. Since this is a wall between bedrooms you might consider adding sound insulation.

Comment: Definitely second @JimStewart on the sound insulation - when I redid my basement I put Roxul Safe'n'Sound in all the interior walls, and it's incredible. It's cheap and quick to do if the walls are open, and totally worth it in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

If I am not mistaken I believe there are 2 things that are going to play a role in this when dealing with older homes from the 50s on back.

1. Meeting fire codes and
2. Will meeting fire codes endanger the integrity of the dwelling based on load bearing capacities.

For instance, many homes back then had rooms with wall to wall knotty pine, plaster in place of drywall, load bearing walls made of all bricks with 2 fireplaces to match. Not to mention, was the roof sheeted or were slats used.

That type of weight starts adding up real fast.

I think a private or city engineer and then/or a city inspector can tell you what the answers are.

Might want to see if you can access the prints of the home if you do not already possess them. It may save you some $$$.

If you get bored or find this interesting here is a link to a live load and dead load calculator. You will quickly see that weight plays a huge factor that is often overlooked when you're talking numbers like 40 lbs per sq ft and a fish tank is in one corner.

http://www.awc.org/codes-standards/calculators-software/spancalc

Comment: With all due respect to the community, if something I say is incorrect and you choose to downvote, then please enlighten us where it is incorrect. I am willing to continue to learn if I am wrong about something. Cheers!

Comment: I think the DV was because this didn't answer the question. You talk about a lot of things and the most useful of them was "inspector can tell you what the answers are". Not my DV, just supposition (6 years later...)